# scrollbar in inner div while parent only has max-height

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

I can't get a simple css construction to work and it frustrates me a lot.

I have an absolute div positioned somewhere in my page with a fixed position. It has a max-height that is a calculation of the containers height minus some margin i want it to have from the bottom like so:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

This works fine.

Then it has two child divs.
The first one changes height but should not scroll.
The second one also changes height (content changes) and should scroll only when the container div can't grow any further.

```
#inner {
  overflow: auto;
  /* and prolly some other stuff... */
}
```

I made a fiddle that has the problem described..
https://jsfiddle.net/qy3dvh7n/

Anyone seeing what i miss?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add `max-height` property to your `#inner` div.
And then scroll appear as it have max-height of div.

https://jsfiddle.net/5zfomxne/4/

Comment: see the comment i made with the previous post. It is not the behavior i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `#inner` to have `max-height` and also set the `height` to 280px so you have 10px `padding` on top and bottom

```
#inner {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 280px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

#header {
  /* this header has a flexible height */
  background-color: green;
}

#inner {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 280px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id=header>here some text to give it height</div>
    <div id="inner">
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; here there should be a scrollbar   ---> <br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      that overflows the this div<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
    </div>
</div>






<div id="container2">
    <div id=header>here some text to give it height</div>
    <div id="inner">
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
      here lots of text<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the blue container has a fixed size. (which it had in my example, for which i'm sorry)
The result i would like is that it scales from 0 to the max-height (as max height is supposed to do)  based on the content of the inner (red) div. When the size of the blue container reaches it's max height, the inner red div overflows.